# What is the Time Complexity of this JAVA program

Tags: java, time-complexity

This code is to find sum of even numbers in Fibonacci sequence. I just wants to know the Time complexity of this program

```
int sum = 2;
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

while (a < 4000000) {
 int c = a;
 a = b;
 b = c + b;
 if (b % 2 == 0) {
  sum += b;
 }
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

I would be thankful  if I get an explanation too.

Comment: I would argue that the upper bound is `O(1)`, since there isn´t actually anything that your program depends on; If you would change `a < 4000000` to `a < someInput`, then it would be a different story, but currently `4000000` is just a constant.

Comment: O(1) since in loop you are using constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this specific code snippet has constant time complexity as it does not have any variable defining the time of execution.

Let's assume that the limit `4000000` defines such variable parameter thus limiting maximum Fibonacci number `Fk < N`:

```java
    public static int sumEvenFibos(int n) {
        int sum = 2;
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int k = 1; // index of Fibonacci number
        while (a < n) {
         int c = a;
         a = b;
         b = c + b;
         if (b % 2 == 0) {
          sum += b;
         }
         k++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("sum=" + sum + "; k=" + k + " for n=" + n);
        return sum;
    }
```

Then this function has lower time complexity than O(N) because the k-th Fibonacci number `a` grows non-linearly according to [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet%27s_formula) which can be expressed asymptotically as: `Fk ~= φ^K / sqrt(5)`, where `φ = (1 + sqrt(5))/2 > 1` is golden ratio.

Thus, in the the loop at most `k` Fibonacci numbers are calculated, that is:

```
Fk < N,   φ^K / sqrt(5) < N  --> φ^K < N * sqrt(5)

hence,
          K < log(N * sqrt(5)) / log (φ)
```

As the constant values can be ignored when defining time complexity, `T(N) = O (log N)`.

The number of `sum` operations for even Fibonacci numbers is `K/3` because each third Fibonacci number is even:
1 1 **2** 3 5 **8** 11 13 **24** etc.

**Test & Output**

```java
    int[] ns = {
        10, 100, 1000, 10_000, 100_000, 
        1000_000, 2000_000, 4000_000, 
        10_000_000, 20_000_000, 40_000_000, 
        80_000_000, 160_000_000
    };
    Arrays.stream(ns).forEach(MyClass::sumEvenFibos);
---------
sum=10; k=6 for n=10
sum=188; k=11 for n=100
sum=3382; k=16 for n=1000
sum=14328; k=20 for n=10000
sum=257114; k=25 for n=100000
sum=1089154; k=30 for n=1000000
sum=4613732; k=31 for n=2000000
sum=4613732; k=33 for n=4000000
sum=19544084; k=35 for n=10000000
sum=19544084; k=36 for n=20000000
sum=82790070; k=38 for n=40000000
sum=82790070; k=39 for n=80000000
sum=350704366; k=40 for n=160000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. You iterate over all elements in the collection - this is `O(n)` or `linear complexity`

Answer (score -1):

The Time complexity of this program will be (n+5)+3+1 = n+9 = o(n) and below is the calculation....

`int sum = 2;      // constant =1

int a = 1;       //constant = 1

int b = 2;       //constant = 1

while (a < 4000000) {  //loop = n

int c = a;       //constant = 1

a = b;           //assigning value = 1

b = c + b;       //assigning value = 1

if (b % 2 == 0) {  //if condition = 1

sum += b;       // addition = 1

}

}

System.out.println(sum);  // output = 1

so the time complexity will be o(n) and short trick of finding time complexity is check loops inside code so if one loop so complexity is n and if nested loop complexity is n^2 and if two loop up and below so complexity is 2n and same for all other. Thanks.

Comment: It's important to say that we use bit O (not a small o here); that's an explanation regarding the differences between two notations - http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/13/lectures/app-b.pdf